# Getting the working directory with JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

There is a `JFileChooser` dialog where a user browse to a location which contains its config file. I want to get that location as the working directory however, `System.getProperty("user.dir")` seems to point to the location where the application starts. How can I fix that?

Assume

```
 D:\netbean\projects\test
```

that is where the application start. Then the user clicks on a button and browse to

```
 D:\configs
```

The code look like

```
File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
myTextArea.setText("Working directory is " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\n" );
```

That points to netbeans folder which is wrong in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` is a system property defined at runtime that is 
 the directory where the JVM was run from.
 It has no relation with the directory that contains the file chosen in a `JFileChooser`.

You can use the `getParentFile()` method of `File` to retrieve the folder that contains the file that was chosen by the user:

```
File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
myTextArea.setText("Parent directory is " + selectedFile.getParentFile() + "\n" );
```

Comment: Excuse me, please see the update post for a minor question related to that.

Comment: You are welcome. I will not edit the answer otherwise it could not make the question and the answer reusable.  I will answer by comment in the next comment. Feel free to open a new question about this new need if my answer is not enough. Do you want that the last place be remembered for the current application running or for all next application running (real persistent data) ?